# If condition met, yet doesn't run in Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Sorry if a silly question.

I have a script that doesn't behave how it's intended even though a condition is met.

My script is something like this:

```sh
    state=$(Substate=running)

    systemctl show -p SubState someservice | while read output
    if [ $output = $state ];
    then
    echo "ok"
    else
    echo "not ok"
    fi
```

I've tried declaring the state variable in different ways but non seem to work;

```sh
    state=$(Substate=running)
    state=Substate=running
    state="Substate=running"
```

also tried `[ $output = $state ] [ "$output" = "$state" ] [[ ]]` but nothing works.

I think I'm declaring the state variable wrong?

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash strings compare is case-sensitive, and the output from systemctl sub-state seems to return `SubState=running` with capital "S" for "State"

And I see you declared your `state` with lower-case s in "state" -

```
state=$(Substate=running)
state=Substate=running
state="Substate=running"
```

So my guess is that your comparing problem relates to case-sensitive string comparison

The following seems to be working for me:

```
state="SubState=running"
output=$(systemctl show -p SubState someservice)

if [ "$output" == "$state" ]
then
echo "ok"
else
echo "not ok"
fi
```

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to answer Saar. For some strange reason the only way I got it to work was  if [[ "$output" -eq "$state" ]]

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand you are trying to check that certain systemctl parameter has the value that you need? This could be achieved with simple grep:

```
$ systemctl show | grep 'LogLevel=info'  && echo ok || echo fail 
LogLevel=info
ok

$ systemctl show | grep 'LogLevel=info2' && echo ok || echo fail 
fail
```